# Reverse engineer a snapshot creation process on AWS / EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am faced with the following situation:

There is an EC2 instance on say `eu-west-1`.

When selecting `Snapshots` on the EC2 service, I see that periodically, every 7 days on the exact same time, a snapshot is taken from the particular image.

The problem is I cannot find:

- any related policy on `Lifecycle Manager` service
- any relevant `Lambda` function that could carry out such a task.

Via what other (managed) means could such a process be carried out periodically with such an accuracy on time?

**edit**: The corresponding `CloudTrail` log entry is:

(actual values regarding user, event and request id have been scrambled of course)

```
AWS access key:
AWS region: eu-west-1
Error code:
Event ID: 454g0236-x4e6-43c1-3565-4xb6d541c2h1
Event name: CreateSnapshot
Event source: ec2.amazonaws.com
Event time: 2019-11-23, 05:00:44 AM
Read only: false
Request ID: zedfbc42-2513-459e-3241-ffcb8442ba44
Source IP address: events.amazonaws.com
User name: g45tg34m3l53mmm53333421knbb43
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple other options,

1. Check Cloudwatch events, if there is any event triggering. Most probably this one is in your case.
2. Cronjob on an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you question you are looking for a way to know if Lifecycle Manager is available for EC2 snapshots.

Below given links should be able to help you on the same.
For enabling a custom Snapshot Lifecycle policy manually refer [Snapshot Lifecycle](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=us-east-1#Lifecycle:sort=PolicyId.)

For automating a solution for the same please refer[automation of snapshot lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html)